# How to load view faster using or without using setOffscreenPageLimit and retain pages?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

As we know that Android viewPager has a setOffscreenPageLimit method to determine the number of invisible pages that should be pre-create and retained.

I have a quiz application that load 10 questions from an API call.

```
if(response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
    data = response.body();
    fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int t = 0; t < response.body().getData().getMcqs().size(); t++) {
        ExerciseQuizFragment practiceQuizFragment = QuizFragment.newInstance(t, null);
        fragments.add(practiceQuizFragment);
    }
    loadViewPagerAndViews();
}
```

In playing quiz user can skip a questions or submit answer and get result on same screen. Every quiz also has a Previous button that user can see his previous stats of that question (is user ans is right/wrong/skipped) which is retained since I use setOffscreenPageLimit like this.

```
private void loadViewPagerAndViews() {
    binding.pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle()));
    binding.pager.setUserInputEnabled(false);
    binding.pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(data.getData().getMcqs().size());
}
```

The quiz view is something liked below:

[image: quiz screenshot]

The problem is since I setOffscreenPageLimit equal to quizes length. The quiz view loads too slower when it is loaded first time. If I use default  setOffscreenPageLimit it load faster but in that case is user device go offscreen all previous users retained stats lost which is available via previous button of quiz view.

How I keep retained user stats pages if I use default setOffscreenPageLimit not quizzes size? Also is there any way where I can load faster using quizzes sizes setOffscreenPageLimit?

Answer (score 0):

You Could try using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of using PagerAdapter as this:-

> Implementation of PagerAdapter that uses a Fragment to manage each page. This class also handles saving and restoring of fragment's state.

Then the default off screen limit of +/- 1 would probably be ok for you as if viewpager does decide to un-cache the fragment the fragment's state should be saved and restored as necessary.